# How to get rid of class name prefix in custom exception message?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, exception

Is there a way to get rid of the class name prefix which is added to message while throwing exception?

```
public class MyException: Exception
{
    public MyException(string message) : base(message){}
}
```

and then

```
throw new MyException("error");
```

will by displayed in console as "MyException: error", but I want it to be just "error".

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're writing it as the following, which prints the string representation of the exception:

```
        try
        {
            // Exception is thrown
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
```

You can instead use, which will only write the exception message:

```
Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
```

Comment: It's in Unity so no Console class